# Parser XML multi-tag

Tags: android, jsoup

i want parse this webpage on my android app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <hello>
        <world>
            <a></a>
            <b><![CDATA[one]]></b>
            <c><![CDATA[two]]></c>
            <d><![CDATA[three]]></d>
            <e><![CDATA[four]]></e>
            <f><![CDATA[five]]></f>

        </world>

        <world>
            <a></a>
            <b><![CDATA[test1]]></b>
            <c><![CDATA[test2]]></c>
            <d><![CDATA[test3]]></d>
            <e><![CDATA[test4]]></e>
            <f><![CDATA[test5]]></f>

        </world>

        <world>
            .....more
        </world>
    </hello>
```

I want extract :
one, two, three, four, five and test1...and more..

Comment: Go through : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Jsoup` in this way:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());
Elements elements = doc.select("hello world *");
for (Element element : elements) {
    if(!element.tagName().equals("a")){             
        System.out.println("Text: " + element.text());
    }
}
```

Output will be:

```
Text: one
Text: two
Text: three
Text: four
Text: five
Text: test1
Text: test2
Text: test3
Text: test4
Text: test5
```